# Error execute shell from java

Tags: aix

I am trying to execute an unix schell script from Java class using Runtime.execute(). But i am getting exitValue 139 while doing this.
 Please find the code snippet:

```
 try{String scriptName = "test.ksh";
String argParameter = "satish"; // parameter passed to ksh 
file.String scriptToBePassed = "/usr/bin/ksh "+scriptName+" "+argParameter;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptToBePassed);
int exitValue = proc.waitFor();
s.o.p("Exit Value is : "+exitValue);}catch(Exception e){  e.printStackTrace();}
```

Step 2) test.ksh file internally calls an exe file and it accepts the arguments.

While running the above code , i am getting 139 exit Value.

and also note that when i am running the script manually it went successful.

Above java code will generates command:
 /usr/bin/ksh test.ksh satish.

The command is used to run manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path for the command
full path means path of the shell script??.
I kept my script on /satish/bexe area.. should i 
use like
/usr/bin/ksh /satish/bexe/test.ksh something like that...